# angularjs $scope.watch text field error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i have used local storage to filter listpage .i have text box with clear button
when i clear button its not working becoze of that $scope.watch.if i enter values in text box also $scope.watch is not allowed the values how to avoid this error when i click clear button.when i clear or ng-model changes i need to pick current value based on that value list should come

```js
.controller('ListingCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window', '$filter','$ionicPopover','$ionicLoading',
    function($scope, $http, $location, $window, $filter, $ionicPopover, $ionicLoading) {
 $scope.$watch(function() {
    var searchstore =window.localStorage.getItem("searchstore");
    console.log(searchstore);
    $scope.query=searchstore;
   })
 $scope.clearSearch = function() 
 {
   $scope.query = '';
 };
 $http.get('*****').success(function(data,dealers,response)
   {  
   $scope.dealers = data;
   
   });
}])
   

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```html
<div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
  <label class="item-input-wrapper" >
    <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="query" >
  </label>
 <button class="button button-icon ion-ios-close-outline"     ng-click="clearSearch()" id="iconcolor"  >clear</button>
</div>
<div class="list card" data-ng-init="nearme()" data-ng-repeat="dealer in dealers |  filter:query ">
     <div class="item item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right" href="#">
      <h2>{{dealer.Store_Name}}</h2> 
      <p>{{dealer.S_Address.area}} {{dealer.S_Address.city}}</p> 
   <p>{{dealer.S_Services}}</p>
  </div> 
  
</div>
```

Comment: but you don't want to delete your "searchstore" in localstorage? btw, there are some mistakes in your code with using $watch

Comment: okey how can i watch when click clear button or ng-model changes values

Comment: that was a question^^ do you?

Comment: then how to use $scope.watch.if i removed $scope.watch local storage some times get null value or old values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work like you want it.

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
  return window.localStorage.getItem("searchstore")
},
function(searchstore) {
  $scope.query = searchstore;
});

$scope.clearSearch = function() {
  // You could remove aswell, but I prefer setting it empty
  // window.localStorage.removeItem("searchstore");
  window.localStorage.setItem("searchstore", "");
};
```